# Python Scatter Plot: Cannot connect points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two lists:

```
x = [5, 5, -5, -5, 10, 10, -10, -10, 15, 15, -15, -15, 20, 20, -20, -20]
y = [-5, 5, 5, -10, -10, 10, 10, -20, -15, 15, 15, -30, -20, 20, 20, -40]
```

plotting the points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

I get:

[image]

but when I want to connect the points, I get:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, "-")
```

> TypeError: ufunc 'sqrt' not supported for the input types, and the
>   inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
>   the casting rule ''safe''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scatter plot just plots the dots, if you want to connect them. You can use
`plot()` function with same arguments of `scatter`

```
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a connected line, you should only use `plt.plot(x,y, '-o')`.

The purpose of a scatter plot, as the name suggests, is to show you a cloud of points which can give a visual sense about how two datasets are correlated independently of the order of the points (pairs). That's why `plt.scatter` does not support line connection of points.

On the other hand,when you plot with lines using `plt.plot`, then you can visually follow the order of the pairs and it is useful for instance when visualizing time series.